# Angular JS - How do you validate the number of digits in a number input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

What we are looking to do is, have an input that only accepts 0 - 24 (for a time entry application).

These are the values the user should be able to enter into the input:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
```

The current code is as follows:

HTML:

```
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input id="time" type="number" placeholder="24" ng-model="$parent.time1" ng-change="onChange(time1)">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="tel" placeholder="24" ng-model="time2" >
            </label>
        </div>
```

JS/Angular:

```
  var savedTime = 0;
   $scope.onChange = function(time) {
      if (time > 23 || currentTime > 2) {
        $scope.time1 = savedTime;
      } else {
        savedTime = time;  
      };
  };
```

This works fine for limiting the numbers, but it doesn't prevent the user from entering unlimited numbers of preceding `0`s, which we don't want.

I tried using `time.toString().length` and adding some validation using that, but turns out, `00000` as a number, when set to string still becomes `"0"`.

Is there a better way to limit the amount of digits to 2?

Thanks muchly.

Comment: ng-maxlength should do, but on another note,  if they user wana write 0003 (donno why), why should you emit an error?

Comment: @TomerW The reason we want to not allow that is due to the fact that this is a time entry application, and that particular text box will be the one they enter "hours" in. And we feel allowing the user to enter "0000003" hours doesn't really make sense, we'd rather limit it to 2 digits. I tried `ng-maxlength`, but it doesn't seem to work, still lets the user enter as many numbers as they want :/

Comment: @TomerW I just tried `ng-maxlength` again. It works, but whenever you exceed 2 digits, instead of blocking further input (which would be ideal) it simply resets the field. Which I suppose is a solution we can work with. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `$scope.time1 = parseInt(savedTime)` to the end of your function-

```
var savedTime = 0;
   $scope.onChange = function(time) {
      if (time > 23 || currentTime > 2) {
        $scope.time1 = savedTime;
      } else {
        savedTime = time;  
      };
      $scope.time1 = parseInt(savedTime);
};
```

Comment: var num = 000;
parseInt(num) -> 0
parseInt(num).length -> 1

Comment: @JoelDamien Put the following into the Chrome debugger console `var num = 00000000000; parseInt(num);` and you get `0`.

Comment: Whoops, accidentally pressed enter. Here's what I meant to post:

`var num = 000;`
`parseInt(num`) -> 0
`parseInt(num).length` -> 1
`parseInt(num).toString().length` -> 1

I need it to parse the length as 3.

Comment: Yes. I know it does, and I don't want it to do that. I want `parseInt(num)` to return how many zeroes are in it.

Comment: @JoelDamien If you want to force 2 chars in the field (although that is not what your example numbers suggest) I'd go with a variation on @ergonaut s answer changing the pattern to `/[0-9]{2}/`

Comment: @JoelDamien `$scope.time1 = parseInt(savedTime);` will replace the input's value with the parsed version of the number since you are using `ng-model="$parent.time1"`.  This means that you don't have to worry about the length of the input. So if the user types `000000000000` the value in the text box will be replaced with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the [ng-maxlength="number"] directive.  Set it to 2 like this:

```
    <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input id="time" type="number" placeholder="24" ng-model="$parent.time1" ng-change="onChange(time1)" ng-maxlength="2">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="tel" placeholder="24" ng-model="time2" ng-maxlength="2">
        </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your input to match a pattern:

```
<input type="number" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,2}$/" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the effect you want to achieve.  You can do something like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/[0-9]{1,2}/" 
               maxlength="2"
               ng-model="myCtrl.title">
```

Which will prevent the user from entering any more than 2 characters.  If the characters are anything but a number, it will set the field class to `ng-invalid-pattern`.

If you don't want to prevent the user from entering two characters and just want to show a validation message if they enter three or more, just remove the maxlength.

Comment: Input type has to be number (so as to only open the number keypad on mobile device). `maxlength` does not work with number type inputs.