# how to limit number Input textbox for hour format 0-24

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

Here is my code:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="model" min="0" max="23" />
```

I'm able to enter values in text box other than MIN MAX I have provided

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936352/html-number-input-min-and-max-not-working-properly

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew despite the lag of tag, I think he is using AngularJS, so a jQuery solution might not be optimal

Comment: Maybe. Also, there is [Angular.JS - only allow up to a certain number value in an input number field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305136), [How to only allow the numbers 0-5 in <input> fields with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500938).. or even [**Angular JS - How do you validate the number of digits in a number input**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757385) (*have an input that only accepts 0 - 24 (for a time entry application).*)